# new mysqli() call works from cli but fails via apache httpd

Tags: php, linux, mysqli, apache2.4, fedora20

summary:new  mysqli() call works from CLI  but not via httpd.

Scenario:
file timetest.php

```
<?php    
$res=new mysqli('hostname/ip','myuser','mypass','mydb',3306,'/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock');
$participants = mysqli_query($res,"myquery");

printf("\tvar panelists=[\n");
$mycount=0;
while ($myrow=mysqli_fetch_object($participants)){
        if ($mycount++ > 0){
                printf("\t\t,");
        } else {
                printf("\t\t");
        }
        printf("{key:%s,label:\"%s\"}\n",$myrow->key,htmlspecialchars($myrow->label));
}
printf("\t\t,{key:0,label:\"unassigned\"}\n\t];\n");

phpinfo();
?>
```

As user apache cli command 'php timetest.php' results in the expected list of data returned from the query.

```
lynx http://hostname/timetest.php
```

returns only the static data and an error in the httpd error log stating:

```
[Tue Nov 04 14:04:33.751527 2014] [:error] [pid 30344] [client 10.0.0.1:37130] PHP Warning:  mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): Permission denied in /opt/www/html/timetest.php on line 2
```

Configuration:

Fedora 20
Apache httpd
PHP Version => 5.5.17

Diff of phpinfo via apache  vs via cli:

```
5,6c5,6
< Build Date => Sep 20 2014 16:26:24
< Server API => Apache 2.0 Handler
---
> Build Date => Sep 20 2014 16:24:06
> Server API => Command Line Interface
79c79
<  
---
> 
85,139d84
< Apache Version => Apache/2.4.10 (Fedora) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips PHP/5.5.17 mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.5 mod_perl/2.0.9-dev Perl/v5.18.2
< Apache API Version => 20120211
< Server Administrator => jgreene@greenemyst.com
< Hostname:Port => www.greenemyst.com:0
< User/Group => apache(48)/48
< Max Requests => Per Child: 0 - Keep Alive: on - Max Per Connection: 100
< Timeouts => Connection: 60 - Keep-Alive: 5
< Virtual Server => No
< Server Root => /etc/httpd
< Loaded Modules => core mod_so http_core mod_access_compat mod_actions mod_alias mod_allowmethods mod_auth_basic mod_auth_digest mod_authn_anon mod_authn_core mod_authn_dbd mod_authn_dbm mod_authn_file mod_authn_socache mod_authz_core mod_authz_dbd mod_authz_dbm mod_authz_groupfile mod_authz_host mod_authz_owner mod_authz_user mod_autoindex mod_cache mod_cache_disk mod_data mod_dbd mod_deflate mod_dir mod_dumpio mod_echo mod_env mod_expires mod_ext_filter mod_filter mod_headers mod_include mod_info mod_log_config mod_logio mod_macro mod_mime_magic mod_mime mod_negotiation mod_remoteip mod_reqtimeout mod_rewrite mod_setenvif mod_slotmem_plain mod_slotmem_shm mod_socache_dbm mod_socache_memcache mod_socache_shmcb mod_status mod_substitute mod_suexec mod_unique_id mod_unixd mod_userdir mod_version mod_vhost_alias mod_dav mod_dav_fs mod_dav_lock mod_lua prefork mod_proxy mod_lbmethod_bybusyness mod_lbmethod_byrequests mod_lbmethod_bytraffic mod_lbmethod_heartbeat mod_proxy_ajp mod_proxy_balancer mod_proxy_connect mod_proxy_express mod_proxy_fcgi mod_proxy_fdpass mod_proxy_ftp mod_proxy_http mod_proxy_scgi mod_ssl mod_systemd mod_cgi mod_perl mod_php5 mod_wsgi
< 
< Directive Local Value Master Value
< engine => 1 => 1
< last_modified => 0 => 0
< xbithack => 0 => 0
< 
< Apache Environment
< Variable Value
< UNIQUE_ID => VFgNbKQDyyi4J2-sYw7u2wAAAAM
< HTTP_USER_AGENT => Wget/1.14 (linux-gnu)
< HTTP_ACCEPT => */*
< HTTP_HOST => localhost
< HTTP_CONNECTION => Keep-Alive
< PATH => /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
< SERVER_SIGNATURE => no value
< SERVER_SOFTWARE => Apache/2.4.10 (Fedora) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips PHP/5.5.17 mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.5 mod_perl/2.0.9-dev Perl/v5.18.2
< SERVER_NAME => localhost
< SERVER_ADDR => ::1
< SERVER_PORT => 80
< REMOTE_ADDR => ::1
< DOCUMENT_ROOT => /opt/www/html
< REQUEST_SCHEME => http
< CONTEXT_PREFIX => no value
< CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT => /opt/www/html
< SERVER_ADMIN => jgreene@greenemyst.com
< SCRIPT_FILENAME => /opt/www/html/timetest.php
< REMOTE_PORT => 49043
< GATEWAY_INTERFACE => CGI/1.1
< SERVER_PROTOCOL => HTTP/1.1
< REQUEST_METHOD => GET
< QUERY_STRING => no value
< REQUEST_URI => /timetest.php
< SCRIPT_NAME => /timetest.php
< 
< HTTP Headers Information
< 
< HTTP Request Headers
< HTTP Request => GET /timetest.php HTTP/1.1
< User-Agent => Wget/1.14 (linux-gnu)
< Accept => */*
< Host => localhost
< Connection => Keep-Alive
< HTTP Response Headers
< X-Powered-By => PHP/5.5.17
< 
192,197c137,142
< highlight.comment => #FF8000 => #FF8000
< highlight.default => #0000BB => #0000BB
< highlight.html => #000000 => #000000
< highlight.keyword => #007700 => #007700
< highlight.string => #DD0000 => #DD0000
< html_errors => On => On
---
> highlight.comment => <font style="color: #FF8000">#FF8000</font> => <font style="color: #FF8000">#FF8000</font>
> highlight.default => <font style="color: #0000BB">#0000BB</font> => <font style="color: #0000BB">#0000BB</font>
> highlight.html => <font style="color: #000000">#000000</font> => <font style="color: #000000">#000000</font>
> highlight.keyword => <font style="color: #007700">#007700</font> => <font style="color: #007700">#007700</font>
> highlight.string => <font style="color: #DD0000">#DD0000</font> => <font style="color: #DD0000">#DD0000</font>
> html_errors => Off => Off
201c146
< implicit_flush => Off => Off
---
> implicit_flush => On => On
208c153
< max_execution_time => 30 => 30
---
> max_execution_time => 0 => 0
211c156
< max_input_time => 60 => 60
---
> max_input_time => -1 => -1
215c160
< output_buffering => 4096 => 4096
---
> output_buffering => 0 => 0
221c166
< register_argc_argv => Off => Off
---
> register_argc_argv => On => On
223c168
< report_zend_debug => On => On
---
> report_zend_debug => Off => Off
603c548
< connect_failure => 1
---
> connect_failure => 0
607c552
< active_connections => 18446744073709551615
---
> active_connections => 0
728a674,677
> pcntl
> 
> pcntl support => enabled
> 
806a756,764
> readline
> 
> Readline Support => enabled
> Readline library => EditLine wrapper
> 
> Directive => Local Value => Master Value
> cli.pager => no value => no value
> cli.prompt => \b \>  => \b \> 
> 
837c795
< session.save_path => /var/lib/php/session => no value
---
> session.save_path => no value => no value
867c825
< soap.wsdl_cache_dir => /var/lib/php/wsdlcache => /tmp
---
> soap.wsdl_cache_dir => /tmp => /tmp
977,979c935,957
< PATH => /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
< LANG => C
< NOTIFY_SOCKET => @/org/freedesktop/systemd1/notify
---
> HOSTNAME => www.greenemyst.com
> SHELL => /bin/bash
> TERM => xterm
> HISTSIZE => 1000
> USER => root
> LS_COLORS => rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=01;05;37;41:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=01;36:*.au=01;36:*.flac=01;36:*.mid=01;36:*.midi=01;36:*.mka=01;36:*.mp3=01;36:*.mpc=01;36:*.ogg=01;36:*.ra=01;36:*.wav=01;36:*.axa=01;36:*.oga=01;36:*.spx=01;36:*.xspf=01;36:
> SUDO_USER => jgreene
> SUDO_UID => 1000
> USERNAME => root
> PATH => /usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
> MAIL => /var/spool/mail/root
> PWD => /opt/home/jgreene
> LANG => en_US.UTF-8
> HISTCONTROL => ignoredups
> SHLVL => 1
> SUDO_COMMAND => /bin/bash
> HOME => /root
> LOGNAME => root
> LESSOPEN => ||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
> SUDO_GID => 1000
> DISPLAY => 10.0.0.253:0.0
> OLDPWD => /etc/php.d
> _ => /bin/php
984,1000c962,986
< _SERVER["UNIQUE_ID"] => VFgNbKQDyyi4J2-sYw7u2wAAAAM
< _SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"] => Wget/1.14 (linux-gnu)
< _SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT"] => */*
< _SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] => localhost
< _SERVER["HTTP_CONNECTION"] => Keep-Alive
< _SERVER["PATH"] => /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
< _SERVER["SERVER_SIGNATURE"] => no value
< _SERVER["SERVER_SOFTWARE"] => Apache/2.4.10 (Fedora) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips PHP/5.5.17 mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.5 mod_perl/2.0.9-dev Perl/v5.18.2
< _SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] => localhost
< _SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"] => ::1
< _SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] => 80
< _SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] => ::1
< _SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] => /opt/www/html
< _SERVER["REQUEST_SCHEME"] => http
< _SERVER["CONTEXT_PREFIX"] => no value
< _SERVER["CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT"] => /opt/www/html
< _SERVER["SERVER_ADMIN"] => jgreene@greenemyst.com
---
> _SERVER["HOSTNAME"] => www.greenemyst.com
> _SERVER["SHELL"] => /bin/bash
> _SERVER["TERM"] => xterm
> _SERVER["HISTSIZE"] => 1000
> _SERVER["USER"] => root
> LS_COLORS => rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=01;05;37;41:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=01;36:*.au=01;36:*.flac=01;36:*.mid=01;36:*.midi=01;36:*.mka=01;36:*.mp3=01;36:*.mpc=01;36:*.ogg=01;36:*.ra=01;36:*.wav=01;36:*.axa=01;36:*.oga=01;36:*.spx=01;36:*.xspf=01;36:
> SUDO_USER => jgreene
> SUDO_UID => 1000
> USERNAME => root
> PATH => /usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
> MAIL => /var/spool/mail/root
> PWD => /opt/home/jgreene
> LANG => en_US.UTF-8
> HISTCONTROL => ignoredups
> SHLVL => 1
> SUDO_COMMAND => /bin/bash
> HOME => /root
> LOGNAME => root
> LESSOPEN => ||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
> SUDO_GID => 1000
> DISPLAY => 10.0.0.253:0.0
> OLDPWD => /etc/php.d
> _ => /bin/php
984,1000c962,986
< _SERVER["UNIQUE_ID"] => VFgNbKQDyyi4J2-sYw7u2wAAAAM
< _SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"] => Wget/1.14 (linux-gnu)
< _SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT"] => */*
< _SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] => localhost
< _SERVER["HTTP_CONNECTION"] => Keep-Alive
< _SERVER["PATH"] => /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
< _SERVER["SERVER_SIGNATURE"] => no value
< _SERVER["SERVER_SOFTWARE"] => Apache/2.4.10 (Fedora) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips PHP/5.5.17 mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.5 mod_perl/2.0.9-dev Perl/v5.18.2
< _SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] => localhost
< _SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"] => ::1
< _SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] => 80
< _SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] => ::1
< _SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] => /opt/www/html
< _SERVER["REQUEST_SCHEME"] => http
< _SERVER["CONTEXT_PREFIX"] => no value
< _SERVER["CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT"] => /opt/www/html
< _SERVER["SERVER_ADMIN"] => jgreene@greenemyst.com
---
> _SERVER["HOSTNAME"] => www.greenemyst.com
> _SERVER["SHELL"] => /bin/bash
> _SERVER["TERM"] => xterm
> _SERVER["HISTSIZE"] => 1000
> _SERVER["USER"] => root
> _SERVER["LS_COLORS"] => rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=01;05;37;41:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=01;36:*.au=01;36:*.flac=01;36:*.mid=01;36:*.midi=01;36:*.mka=01;36:*.mp3=01;36:*.mpc=01;36:*.ogg=01;36:*.ra=01;36:*.wav=01;36:*.axa=01;36:*.oga=01;36:*.spx=01;36:*.xspf=01;36:
> _SERVER["SUDO_USER"] => jgreene
> _SERVER["SUDO_UID"] => 1000
> _SERVER["USERNAME"] => root
> _SERVER["PATH"] => /usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
> _SERVER["MAIL"] => /var/spool/mail/root
> _SERVER["PWD"] => /opt/home/jgreene
> _SERVER["LANG"] => en_US.UTF-8
> _SERVER["HISTCONTROL"] => ignoredups
> _SERVER["SHLVL"] => 1
> _SERVER["SUDO_COMMAND"] => /bin/bash
> _SERVER["HOME"] => /root
> _SERVER["LOGNAME"] => root
> _SERVER["LESSOPEN"] => ||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
> _SERVER["SUDO_GID"] => 1000
> _SERVER["DISPLAY"] => 10.0.0.253:0.0
> _SERVER["OLDPWD"] => /etc/php.d
> _SERVER["_"] => /bin/php
> _SERVER["PHP_SELF"] => /opt/www/html/timetest.php
> _SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] => /opt/www/html/timetest.php
1002,1159c988,995
< _SERVER["REMOTE_PORT"] => 49043
< _SERVER["GATEWAY_INTERFACE"] => CGI/1.1
< _SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] => HTTP/1.1
< _SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] => GET
< _SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] => no value
< _SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] => /timetest.php
< _SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] => /timetest.php
< _SERVER["PHP_SELF"] => /timetest.php
< _SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"] => 1415056748.134
< _SERVER["REQUEST_TIME"] => 1415056748
---
> _SERVER["PATH_TRANSLATED"] => /opt/www/html/timetest.php
> _SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] => 
> _SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"] => 1415058863.3695
> _SERVER["REQUEST_TIME"] => 1415058863
> _SERVER["argv"] => Array
> (
>     [0] => /opt/www/html/timetest.php
> )
1160a997
> _SERVER["argc"] => 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1' for the win!
SELinux was blocking db access from httpd.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the permission for the mysql.lock file has to be checked. Have a look at the file/directory permissions and see if apache can access those resources.

Comment: `# ls -ld /var/{,lib/{,mysql/{,mysql.sock}}}
drwxr-xr-x. 24 root  root   4096 Nov  4 13:27 /var/
drwxrwxr-x. 54 root  root   4096 Nov  4 12:04 /var/lib/
drwxr-xr-x. 24 mysql mysql 16384 Oct 21 11:19 /var/lib/mysql/
srwxrwxrwx.  1 mysql mysql     0 Oct 21 11:19 /var/lib/mysq/mysql.sock` If it was file permissions on the socket I'd have gotten that. Note as the apache user (which is what the httpd runs as), it still works using the php cli invocation. Additionally I've also used IPs to induce it to use the 3306 port and the same symptoms occur.

Comment: Admittedly it is REALLY weird. Almost as if the php is operating in a chroot environment, but  my other tests showed it wasn't. The primary difference in the phpinfo it the presence/invocation by apache2handler.